# Если один пользователь открыл страницу и она закешилась в Redis, то все, кто откроет эту же страницу, получит ее из кеша?

Tags: laravel, redis

Т.е. один пользователь вообще с другого компа зайдет на сайт, то уже по такому же запросу, что был закешен, то получит из кеша?

Я проверил на локалке с одного браузера: зашел, закешилось в Redis; зашел с другого на туже страницу, и уже не появилась 2 строка кеша.

Выходит, что если задаем время жизни кеша, то с периодичностью этот кеш обновит тот юзер кто первый запросить эту страницу из БД(когда закончится время кеша)для всех остальных и все остальные пользовыатели будут получать ее из REDIS а не из БД

Comment: Смотря как вы кешируете, если вы кешируете с каким то модификаторм ключа относящемуся к пользователю то у каждого пользователя будет своя страница...